# Remove 'Now' button from jsfile of timepicker jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, timepicker

Does anyone know how to remove the "Now" button from the jquery timepicker add on file?

I removed the `var currentText = 'Now'`, and this change removes the text, but the button is still there, labelled **"Today"** instead of **"Now"**. I do not need this button in the timepicker.

I am using Trent Richardson's timepicker.

The timepicker can be seen on this website: [click here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

The js file can be seen here, [click here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Now' button replaces the Today button normally, but without text it uses the default.

In your CSS, simply set the now button to "display: none;"

If I remember correctly, you can set this in the .ui-priority-secondary - but not sure if it is used elsewhere.. have a play, but this should be your solution, just depends on usage.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer here:

I am using the Yii extension and added the code found at the site below to my css/main.css file.  Voila!

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-now-in-timepicker

Comment: Yes, as in the answer above, this code simply adds 'display: none;' to the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS, Works fine for me.

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
float:left;
background: #900;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide all the buttons of the calendar set the property `showButtonPanel` with `false`

```
$("#inputDate").datetimepicker({showButtonPanel: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following property to `.timepicker()` solved my problem:

```
minDate: new Date(2080, 1, 1)
```

Just provide very *long date* which disables **`now`** button by itself.

**So the final code is:**

```
$('#time-duration-box').timepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2050, 1, 1)
});
```

Comment: This hides the "now" button, but also makes it impossible to do anything useful with the timepicker.